# Nexus 9 Emulator not showing in AVD

Tags: android, sdk, adt

Nexus 9 emulator is not showing on avd. I have updated my adt and sdk manager. Emulated android tv and other device are showing. But nexus 9 isn't showing.
**Can you please tell me which emulator is running on nexus 9**

Answer (score 0):

This is my Nexus 9 Android Virtual Device (AVD) settings. I cloned it from Nexus 10 and modified its resolution.

This posting is very similar with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30801841/how-to-add-nexus-9-in-avd-manager/37767203#37767203).

[image]