# How to add Nexus 9 in AVD manager?

Tags: android

M preview supports devices like nexus 5, nexus 6, nexus 9 but unfortunately in my AVD manager none of these are listed. So how to add these virtual devices in my AVD manager virtual devices?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking for Android Studio, you just go to Tools>>Android>>AVD Manager. In the window that opens, at the bottom there's a button to create new devices.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with the android studio you have a little button in preview of layouts, for defect is Nexus 4 I think but if you click you can select device.
Tell me if I helped you and good programming!

Answer (score 1):

When you're in Android, hit Tools >> Android >> AVD Manager.  That'll take you to the screen where you can manage your virtual devices.

Next, hit *Create virtual device* button on the bottom-left of the window that opens up.

Then you'll see a list of all of the different types of devices that you can create.

Here is where I think you got lost...

On the left side of this window, you'll see a menu of different types of devices that you can create -- TV, Wear, Phone, and Tablet.

Hit the Tablet button, and you'll see a list of different tablets that you can emulate.  The Nexus 9 will be one of them.

Comment: I can't believe I missed this! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is my Nexus 9 Android Virtual Device (AVD) settings. I cloned it from Nexus 10 and modified its resolution.

[image]